# Python: Removing Leading Zeros in the Filename of Every File in a Folder and Subfolders

Tags: python, module, operating-system

I would think that this is a basic task but most of my searches refer to adding zeros.  I just want to strip the leading zeros from every file. I have files like "01.jpg, 02.jpg... 09.jpg".

Chapter 9 of Automate the Boring Stuff talks specifically about using python for this task but does not go over any examples of this.

```
import os, sys
for filename in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))):
```

Well that is the start of what I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get all files under your root folder:

`files = []
for root, directories, file_names in os.walk(unicode(path)):
   for filename in file_names:
        files.append((filename, root))
return files`

then simply iterate over the files and rename:

`for f, p in files:
    if f.startswith('0'):
        os.rename(os.path.join(p, f), os.path.join(p, f[1:])`

Comment: Thbak you for the prompt response. I attempted to use this code but I may be running into a problem when formatting it without the comments. The program gets to the first colon and says "invalid syntax".

Comment: I removed the comments

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, sys
for filename in os.listdir(file folder):
    os.rename(filename, filename[1:])
```

It removes the first char from all file names (in your case, the '0' that you want to get rid of). I recommend using it with caution because it's irreversible.